# Real Time Understanding

Tags: web, real-time

what does real time mean? as per my understanding, real time is meant to update live data. But in this case i`m confused with an e-commerce site. What i do is, I update things in admin panel and the user panel (the actual site) is updated. So is this also real time ?

Please clarify my understanding here.

Kind Regards,

Comment: When you send something to the user view without any request of the user, you are doing a [push](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology)... so usually real time system use the push to update data in "real-time" to the client.

Comment: is this similar to e-commerce as i update the admin site and the user site is updated? because this is also done without the user request, then whats the basic difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[From Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_web) :

> The real-time web is a set of technologies and practices that enable users to receive information as soon as it is published by its authors, rather than requiring that they or their software check a source periodically for updates.

According to this definition of Real-time in web technologies, the answer of fmodos is acceptable.

Is also acceptable any technical solution that would do the update of the content without requiring any user interaction with the website : Ajax-methods, Push-methods, Timer/Loop-methods, also represent a valid option in your case.